# MIPS GCC compiling wrong MIPS release?

Tags: mips, cross-compiling, codesourcery

I'm looking to plunge into the realm of router hacking. Currently, I'm just trying to get a simple hello world to run on my router, a F7D7302 v1, running dd-wrt. cpuinfo reveals a BCM4716, and "MIPS 74K V4.0" as the cpu 'model.'

I downloaded CodeSourcery's MIPS cross-compiler. It was pretty simple to get a compiled executable from that point on. I transferred the file, chmod +x'd the file, and it didn't run.

I decided to do a big of snooping and ran 'file' on the router's busybox executable:

```
[root@LIENUX bin]# file /tmp/busybox
/tmp/busybox: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), corrupted section header size
```

And running 'file' on my hello world:

```
[root@LIENUX bin]# file test
test: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, with unknown capability 0xf41 = 0x756e6700, with unknown capability 0x70100 = 0x1040000, not stripped
```

Running test on the router with static libraries caused a 100% CPU hang; running with dynamic libraries caused a 'not found' error. All appropriate permissions were set.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you grabbed the wrong compiler chain; can you roll a "toolchain-mipsel_x.y.z_BRCM24" from [uclibc](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/)?

Comment: Are you referring to the dd-wrt toolchain? I've that installed as well. I am trying that toolset out right now.. looks promising, similar to the busybox file command!

Comment: Yes. FYI, You can also roll your own.

Comment: In what terms? My own toolchain for the specific processor? Sorry for the probably silly question.

Comment: Also, that didn't work for compiling. Both static/dynamically linked executables returned without any output :(

Comment: https://godbolt.org/ now has a mips compiler (a few actualy)